# About the question of Truth Table

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In general, the number of truth table rows is $\textbf{2}^\textbf{n},$ where $n$ is the number of variables.

But if a variable appears, for example, $q$ appears twice, is it considered a calculation of one or two variables?

Also, if there are variables $q$ and $~q,$ then is it one or two variables?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: please use LaTeX to format your question properly

Comment: With $n$ variables there will be $2^n$ rows in the truth table. It does not matter if $p$ appears twice or something like that.

Comment: To be clear, $n$ is the count for *distinct* literals in the expression.

Comment: If you use \sim instead of ~ the q and ~q will render appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Repetitions of, say '$q$,' count as the same variable, so it would be considered one variable. The definition is the same as for an equation in algebra, like $x^2+x =0.$ The unknown 'x' counts as just one unknown.

Answer (score 1):

> In general, the number of truth table rows is $\mathbf{2^n},$ where $n$ is the number of variables.

To be clear, $n$ is the count for *distinct* variables in the expression.

The truth table for $(p\to q)\to((p\to r)\to (q\to r))$ will have $2^3$ rows.